# Java3D, How to alter the View Platform clip distance?

Tags: java, java-3d, clip

I'm working using Java3D, and I've been manipulating the viewPlatform so that I can 'zoom' in and out of a model which is fine. However, at some point the when I get too close (or too far away) the model is clipped so my question is how do I return (get) the values that these are alter (set) them to suit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javax.media.j3d.View.setBackClipDistance(double distance)
javax.media.j3d.View.setFrontClipDistance(double distance)
```

Comment: Thanks for you're input.   <br/>   <br/> I think that I am having problems getting my head round the view, viewer, viewPlatform. Everytime I think I've cracked it there is another element to consider.